# Form still shows despite PHP condition with session

Tags: php, forms, session, post, session-variables

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))  { ?>
        <div id="login">

            <form method="post" action="login.php">
                Username: <input type="text" name="nm" /> <br />
                Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /> <br />
                <input type="submit" name="go" value="Login" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php } else echo 'hi'; ?>
```

Even though the session is set (value is Test) it shows the form instead of 'Hi'.

Comment: what does `var_dump($_SESSION['login'])` tell you?

Comment: Are you making sure to call `session_start()` at the beginning of the script?

Comment: How are you setting your session can you post the code please

Comment: session_start(); is in the beginning of config.php page which is require_onced in the top of the page. var_dump on that page tells nothing.

Comment: Session is set here in login.php:
$np = $_POST['nm'];
$_SESSION['login'] = $np;

Comment: And what's coming in $_POST['nm']

Comment: Test, and when I var_dump in config.php and run it it reads string(4) "Test"

Comment: Can you echo the session to check if the session is actually set or not

Comment: It doesn't show anything when I echo it.

Comment: @MichaelNaidis If you have `session_start();` inside `config.php`, take it out (to test) and put `<?php session_start(); ?>` above `<?php require_once("config.php");` in all your files, and see what that does. Remember, `session_start();` needs to be in every file, so I don't know what you include(d) in your other files.